# CC.NET configuration preprocessor conditional statements and Windows environment

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

CruiseControl.NET's configuration preprocessor isn't reading my Windows environment like I am expecting it to.  Here's a simple ccnet.config to demonstrate the problem:

```
    <cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" xmlns="http://thoughtworks.org/ccnet/1/8">
        <cb:if expr="'$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)' == 'x86'">
            <cb:define devenvExecutable="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" />
        </cb:if>
        <cb:else>
            <cb:define devenvExecutable="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" />
        </cb:else>

        <project name="test1" >
            <tasks>
                <dumpValue>
                    <xmlFileName>somefile.xml</xmlFileName>
                    <dumpValueItems>
                        <dumpValueItem name="PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE" value="$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)" />
                        <dumpValueItem name="devenvExecutable" value="$(devenvExecutable)" />
                    </dumpValueItems>
                </dumpValue>
            </tasks>
        </project>
    </cruisecontrol>
```

When I open the above file in CCValidator on a machine running Windows 7 64-bit and environment variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64, in the "Processed" output tab of CCValidator it shows:

```
<tasks>
  <dumpValue>
    <dynamicValues />
    <environment />
    <dumpValueItems>
      <dumpValueItem>
        <name>PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE</name>
        <value>x86</value>
        <valueInCDATA>True</valueInCDATA>
      </dumpValueItem>
      <dumpValueItem>
        <name>devenvExecutable</name>
        <value>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com</value>
        <valueInCDATA>True</valueInCDATA>
      </dumpValueItem>
    </dumpValueItems>
    <xmlFileName>somefile.xml</xmlFileName>
  </dumpValue>
</tasks>
```

I'm expecting PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE to show as AMD64 and consequently the devenvExecutable to use the (x86) path.  Why isn't it reading my Windows environment properly?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Olivier Sannier over on the cruisecontrolnet.org help forum for answering this.  Posting the answer here for completeness.  Since CC.Net is a 32-bit process it runs under WOW on a 64-bit O/S; inside WOW, the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable value is "x86".  I used the PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER environment variable to get past the problem:

```
<cb:if expr="'$(PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER)'.Contains(&quot;x86&quot;)">
   <cb:define devenvExecutable="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" />
</cb:if>
<cb:else>
   <cb:define devenvExecutable="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" />
</cb:else>
```

Link to thread on CC.NET help forum is [here](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/boards/2/topics/548?r=565).